# Vue.js app not any errors but white page and keep loading

Tags: vue.js

All of a sudden, I couldn't open the Vue page. It was running fine before, but now the page keeps loading all the time, and there is no error in the console. I can open other pages, so the network should not have problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jhG8.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BEJS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBFik.png)

Comment: Please do not post pictures of codes. Second, provides information to your question

Comment: First, I did not post any pictures of codes. Second, I have provided all the information.

Comment: We can't guess what's happening in your app from an empty console and a bunch of request headers, please provide more details. What does it mean "it was running fine before"? "Before" when? Did you change anything? If the app is supposed to fetch data from an API, can you check the API is up?

Comment: I didn't change anything in the code and all the APIs are up. I thought it is related to the network config that I don't know, so I want to find why.

Comment: I can use it with the ngnix but cannot run it directly, but a few minutes ago, it ran well.

Comment: Try to debug! Maybe commenting out every thing and add "hello world". So you could exclude the issue step by step. Also check, if it's a problem from your file or from your server or from your .htaccess or something.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, everyone. I found the solution with the help of my colleagues. It's because the port 8080 is occupied. I used `vagrant halt` before, but I don't know why it was not closed completely, so after I `vagrant up` and `yarn run serve`, the page cannot be open.